# Sum over partition not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I've got some code with the partition function, but it's not working.

I get an error message that says

> Incorrect syntax near 'Sales'

Does anyone know why? I looked at the other partition questions, didn't find an answer,

The code (below) is supposed to select PriceZoneID and Sales from the Aggregated Sales History table then sum up the total sales using the OVER function and put that data in a new column called Total Sales.

It should then sum up the sales for each zone using the OVER (PARTITION) expression in a new column called TotalSalesByZone then order the data by Price Zone ID and Sales

```
Select PriceZoneID, 
    Sales,
SUM(Sales) OVER () AS Total Sales, 
SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID) AS TotalSalesByZone
From AggregatedSalesHistory
ORDER BY PriceZoneID AND Sales;
```

(Partition By divides the result into Partitions eg Zones)

If you could post the code with the correct answer, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your error? Expected result? Sample data? And why do you want total sum on all columns? Thats likely where your error is

Comment: Your problem is your choice of alias, specially `AS Total Sales`. A column's alias/name cannot contain a whitespace, or other special characters, unless the alias/name is quoted: `AS [Total Sales]` Ideally, however, don't use special characters in your object names, aliases. CamelCase is perfectly acceptable: `AS TotalSales`

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the prompt response. I get an error that says - Incorrect syntax near 'Sales.' What would be a better way of writing the query instead using the partition function? Can you please advise? TIA.

Comment: SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID) AS TotalSalesByZone . It  will also throw error. Because partition requires order by some column.

Comment: @saravanatn no it doesn't. Adding an `ORDER BY` on a `SUM() (PARTITION BY...)` would cause the `SUM` to be a "running total", not a cumulative total.

Comment: Hi Larnu, when I added the square brackets to the query, I got an error message saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'."

Comment: `AND` isn't in the query you've supplied. That error is not relevant for the SQL you have provided.

Comment: @saravanatn See the difference here between including and excluding `ORDER BY` in an `OVER` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/565fc/1. They give very different results.

Comment: That's strange - I'd copied and pasted it over. I'd like to order the query by price zone and sales. Is that not possible?

Comment: I'll have a look at that link that you just sent.

Comment: The correct syntax for multiple columns in an `ORDER BY` is to delimited them by a comma (`,`). Thus `ORDER BY PriceZoneID, Sales;`

Comment: @larnu ok got it

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but I still get an error message? Select 
 PriceZoneID, 
 Sales,
 SUM(Sales) OVER () AS Total Sales, 
 SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID) AS TotalSalesByZone
From AggregatedSalesHistory
ORDER BY 
  PriceZoneID, Sales;

Comment: It says Incorrect syntax near 'Sales'. Do you know what I should change in the code to make it run correctly? TIA.

Comment: Why is the space back in your alias..? See my answer before; you need to fix both problems **at the same time**, not one or the other. I've also, however, voted to close this as a typographical error.

Answer (score 4):

Coming out of the comments now, as it's getting a little silly to correct the errors in there. There is 1 typograhical error in your code, and 1 syntax error:

```
Select PriceZoneID, 
       Sales,
       SUM(Sales) OVER () AS Total Sales, --There's a space in the alias
       SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID) AS TotalSalesByZone
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
ORDER BY PriceZoneID AND Sales; --AND is not valid in an ORDER BY clause
```

The correct query would be:

```
Select PriceZoneID, 
       Sales,
       SUM(Sales) OVER () AS TotalSales, --Removed Space
       SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID) AS TotalSalesByZone
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
ORDER BY PriceZoneID, Sales; --Comma delimited
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for tidying that up. I appreciate it. When I run the tidied up code, I now get an error that says Invalid object name 'AggregatedSalesHistory'. Do you know what that could mean?

Comment: @Mr2017 it means exactly what it says; that the object `AggregatedSalesHistory` doesn't exist. I had *assumed* that the name of your object was correct in your provided SQL. I can't help you with correcting the name, as I have no idea what it is called. You'll need to correct the name.

Comment: Actually, there is a drop down section in the top left hand side of the screen where the default option is 'Master'  - when I changed that to PS55 (a database that inlcudes the aggregated sales history table), the query worked. I need to find out whether I can change the default database from 'Master' to 'PS55' as it's an easy thing to forget.

Comment: You can change the default database for a login yes. If you're working in SSMS, however, it's also normally best to put `USE [Your Database Name];` at the start; just to make sure.

Comment: And the query is now working!! Hurrah! Thanks for your help! The only query I have about it now is that it returns the same results repeatedly.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, going forward - that's a good tip re using USE [database name] at the beginning. If you have any thoughts about the repeated results, please let me know.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"returns the same results repeatedly*". Maybe time to ask a new question, and include **sample data** and expected results

Comment: Ok. I will do. Thanks.