# Partition query returning repeated results

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a partition query which is returning repeated results.

Does anyone know why?

I'm trying to sum up sales by zone from a table called the aggregated sales history table using the partition function. I need to give an example of how it can be used.

The code is below and a snapshot of the results is below.

```
Select PriceZoneID, 
       Sales,
       SUM(Sales) OVER () AS TotalSales, --Removed Space
       SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID) AS TotalSalesByZone
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
ORDER BY PriceZoneID, Sales;
```

[image: Results]

Comment: This sure looks familiar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188799/sum-over-partition-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a GROUP BY to limit the results.

```
Select PriceZoneID, 
       Sales,
       SUM(Sales) OVER () AS TotalSales --Removed Space
       --SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID) AS TotalSalesByZone
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
GROUP BY PriceZoneID, Sales
ORDER BY PriceZoneID, Sales;
```

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for the prompt response. When I tried to run the code above, however, I got an error message that said "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'." Is there something missing? TIA.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed gratitude, but just wanted to say thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. If this helped you solve the issue then mark this as the answer.

Comment: I voted 'up' for both your answer and  ScSimon's, but it's showing '0' instead of 1, for some reason? Do you know how I can change that? It did say that my vote was counted.....

Comment: No clue. Generally there is a check mark icon with a green color that you check  to mark an answer. The upticks may require a higher reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as designed.

```
SUM(Sales) OVER ()
```

This will take the sum of the `Sales` column for **all rows** and place that value in a new column. This, this will be the same value for all rows.

```
SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY PriceZoneID)
```

This will take the sum of the `Sales` column grouped by (or partitioned by) the `PrizeZoneID` and place that value in a new column. Thus, you'll see the same value per `PriceZoneID`.

If you want a roll up, then add a group by and remove the over clause.

```
Select PriceZoneID, 
       SUM(Sales) AS TotalSalesByZone
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
GROUP BY PriceZoneID
ORDER BY PriceZoneID
```

Comment: Hi scsimon, thanks for your response. I need to give an example using the PARTITION function. Is it not possible to do it using the inputs I originally provided?

Comment: Yes, you can use the partition by. But the results you got are correct. If you want a roll up then use my last query

Comment: Hi ScSimon, apologies for the delayed gratitude - there were some other things I needed to work on, but the explanation above was useful. If you know how to add commas to the results, please let me know. So instead of getting 123456 in the results for total sales, I'd like to get 123,456. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decimals don’t have formats in the database although you can use FORMAT() in 2012. I’d handle this on the front end

Comment: Ok, great. Using format worked! Thanks for your help!